# How to recognize if CGPoint is included in shape?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a beginner in quartz.

I'm wonderring a way that recognize if CGPoint is included in shape.

Please give me a help of Expert.

Follow is concept diagram.

[image]

In above three case,
Result I want is YES, Because three RED CGPoint is included in shape.

It is possible like follow way?

```
CGPoint RedPoint1 = {200,100};
CGPoint RedPoint2 = {200,200};
CGPoint RedPoint3 = {350,300};

BOOL includeRect;
includeRect = CGRectContainsPoint(RectCase, RedPoint1);

BOOL includeCircle;
includeCircle = CG ? ContainsPoint(CircleCase, RedPoint2)

BOOL includeBoldLine;
includeBoldLine = CG ? ContainsPoint(BoldLineCase, RedPoint3);
```

Comment: CGRectContainsPoint will only help you for axis aligned CGRects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ease of this all depends on how your shapes are defined.

If you have these as `CGPathRefs` or `NSBezierPaths` there is a `containsPoint:` method you could use.

If these are CGRects that have a transform applied to them, you can use the CGAffineTransformPoint methods to move the point into the same coordinate space and then use `CGRectContainsPoint`